# Transformers Pipeline from Huggingface

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am trying out the transformers pipeline from huggingface:

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers#installation

[image]

When I run on my system, I get a different result.

```
>>> import transformers
>>> transformers.__version__
'2.8.0'
```

I am running on Python 3.7.6.

```
>>> from transformers import pipeline
>>> nlp = pipeline('sentiment-analysis')
Downloading: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 230/230 [00:00<00:00, 77.3kB/s]
2020-04-08 18:04:33.862653: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:319] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
2020-04-08 18:04:33.931454: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fa52e6b7be0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-08 18:04:33.931486: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
>>> nlp('We are very happy to include pipeline into the transformers repository.')
[{'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.94570833}]
>>>
```

What can I look into?

Comment: Which version of transformers are you running? Also, pleae make sure to include your code and the references as actual textual content.

Comment: I can reproduce the original huggingface results with version `2.6.0`.

Comment: I have updated code to textual format. I am using transformers ver: 2.8.0 and python ver: 3.7

Comment: Are you using PyTorch or Tensorflow in your backend? I can still reproduce the `POSITIVE` label, even when using transformers 2.8 (and PyTorch 1.4 as backend)

Comment: I am having Tensorflow '2.1.0'.
I am runing TensorFlow on backend. If i run on Google Colab on Python 3.6, I get correct POSITIVE label.  Don't know why i am getting NEGATIVE label on my MacOS 10.14.5 running on Python 3.7

Comment: I'm still getting the correct result, even with TensorFlow as backend, so I think this might be a problem on your end. Have you tried uninstalling the locally saved model, or re-install the library?

Comment: Please try it by also specifying the model name, like so: `nlp = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model="distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english")`, and see if this changes the result.